# Is it appropriate to share photos of life events with co-workers?

Tags: professionalism, relationships

I noticed some people send photos of their new baby. Is it okay to also send photos of a new house? An email blast to everyone in the company you know (all of them BCCed).

If it is okay to share photos of a baby, where does one draw the line in terms of major life events that you want to share with the workplace?

I understand this might be subjective and depend on the culture of the particular workplace but any thoughts you can offer will be appreciated.

Comment: A "major life event" usually consists of someone being added or removed from your life. Generally speaking when someone is added that is considered worthy of a share like getting married, or having children, or adopting a child, etc. A house isn't really considered a "major life" event unless you're also got married in it or you're bringing home that newborn baby.

Comment: This is kinda what sites like Facebook and Instagram do best, sharing this sort of thing with your friends, family, and coworkers.    Why do you feel that Email is the right platform for you?

Answer (score 5):

I promise you that if you send coworkers pictures of your house, they will start viewing you extremely negatively.  Seriously, new babies are pretty much it. Anything else and you're bound to annoy some people.

Even with babies, it's one of those things you do once. If you keep doing it, it definitely annoys people.

But a house? No, you'll look like you're bragging that you have money.

Comment: +1 spot on.. even with babies some people will *think* you're a d-bag but babies are a Sacred Topic and therefore they would never dare express it

Comment: I agree. New born babies are I believe one time it's appropriate to send personal photos. Your co-workers probably already know you are expecting and are usually supportive and like to see the new baby! I had one of my co-workers email everyone in our department pictures (he was gone for a week) after his son was born. We all excited and happy for him but that's where it should stop.

Comment: Also worth of note it might raise some financial concerns in certain sectors since showboating a new car, house, or something you just bought of high value might be worth looking into on how you got such money or how you paid for it. Ex. you're always complaining about money but suddenly bought a brand new house and you're working for the government.

Comment: And a side effect of that could be never getting a raise. "What do you mean you need more money? With that house, it looks like you have plenty" may not actually be said but certainly could be an underlying justification for not getting one.

Comment: *they will start viewing you as a d-bag.* - Citation Needed

Comment: 32 years in the workplace.  I cite myself and my own experience.

Answer (score 0):

> An email blast to everyone in the company you know (all of them BCCed)

At some companies, using BCC **will get your wrote up**.  Do not use BCC for personal stuff and definitely do not blast the whole company with email in that way.

I would suggest not sharing personal types of photos period via work email.  YMMV

Comment: Our work has a shared directory for people to put their vacation photos, etc, and then people just send an email blast around saying "posted my tropical paradise trip photos in sub-directory 'X' for anyone who is interested."

Comment: We literally had a huge wall full of what pictures people thought were necessary.....It was awful....

Answer (score 0):

An individual BCCing anything to the whole company about their personal lives is just not something that should be done. However, in my experience, a picture of a new baby is sent out to everybody in the office in order to accomplish two things. First, everybody's going to ask about the baby and it gets disruptive. Some people are truly interested and some people just feel obligated. The new parent either can't resist getting drawn into long conversations or gets frustrated and overwhelmed. Second, it's a much less heartless-seeming way to announce that an employee may be out of the office for a period or may have an unpredictable schedule, and plans can be shifted to compensate rather than causing all kinds of pile-ups.